# rotation using plane normal

Tags: c++, opengl, physics

I have a plane in the origin.

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(-10.0, -10.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(10.0, -10.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(10.0, 10.0,  0.0);
glVertex3f(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

Than I am trying to rotate this plane for a new normal 1 0 0.

I understand that To calculate the angle between the two normals, I need to find the old normal. How can I find the old normal? and when I find the old normal do I have to enter in the new normal to rotate, like `glRotatef(angle,1,0,0)`?

Comment: You don't need to "find the old normal", because 1 there isn't any "old normal" and 2 you need to calculate the normal according to the vertices.

Comment: Do you mean like using 3 points and finding vectors such as PQ and PR and than cross product these two vectors? When I do that I get 0 because i dont have depth on my plane

Comment: Didn't see that you didn't use z/depth well, if you aren't using depth then the normal would always be `(X,Y,Z) = (0, 0, 1)`

Comment: What resource are you learning OpenGL from? The code you have shown is using very old deprecated functionality. For new code never use `glBegin`/`glEnd` and friends. You should use modern (3.3+) functionality, such as vertex buffer objects, instead. There are several good free tutorials available online for using modern OpenGL. OpenGL is not designed (excluding old deprecated features) for any functionality other than controlling and passing data to the GPU. You can't use it to perform CPU vector and matrix maths. Use a maths library if you want to do that, then pass the results to OpenGL.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the answers. Another question is when I am trying to rotate it. I know I need to use glrotatef but what do I put in it. Glrotatef(angle, new normal x, new normal y, new normal z)?

Comment: First stop calling it normal, it's just a vector. glRotate(angle, x, y, z); where angle is in degrees (not radians) and x, y, z, is a vector the vector will get normalized if that is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your vertices lie within the XY plane and therefore your normal is simply in the Z direction (0,0,1) or (0,0,-1).  If you want to rotate you polygon to point its normal in the X direction you will need to rotate it 90 degrees about the Y axis, glRotatef(90.0f,0,1,0) or glRotatef(-90.0f,0,1,0).